# Where would the dark matter particle fit inside a picture of the standard model of particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model

Where would the [dark matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) particle fit inside a picture of the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics?

While I am particularly fond of the Sterile Neutrino, I have not been able to find any example of a picture of the standard model arrangement of particles, with Dark Matter (and the Higgs), inside a table. Does one exist? And if not, where would you put it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_CP_problem  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion

Comment: The "and where would you put it" part seems a bit [opinion-based](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 9):

Dark matter candidates are all "beyond the standard model" physics, which means that they represent an extension of the model into something more comprehensive.

Some of these extensions are pretty minimal (I think both axions and massive, sterile neutrinos are in that category) others are quite comprehensive.

Many theorists have favorite models and experimenters have preferences about which to looks for, but as yet there is no solid data on what dark matter *is*: just a significant amount of data on what it is *not*.